# What up with my cat's eye boggie?

Tags: cats, diseases

It's a milky white discharge, but with along black 'thread' coming out of it.

Here's a picture if that's hard to imagine:

[image: Boogers]

I've not noticed anything else wrong with, no red eyes, or difficulty breathing.

I know sometime a little eye discharge is normal, but I'm slightly concerned by the black bit... It's longed like a really long hair.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No concerns, sometimes the "eye boogers" can dry up at the tip or have debris/hair accumulate to it for it to look like this.

Abnormal discharge from eyes can appear green/yellow tinged or can be in excess (around the eye will seem very wet), sclera (white of the eye) may become red, animal may be squinting from discomfort. Animals with painful eyes also tend to paw at them or rub them on surfaces frequently.

If you feel that the eyes are painful be sure to never administer eye drops without seeing a veterinarian first as it may irritate the eye further.